# IllegalStateException for RealmObject after copyFromRealm

Tags: android, realm

I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.
```

when calling an accessor of an object even after the object has been detached from Realm with `realm.copyFromRealm()`.

My understanding of the Realm documentation was that once I copy the object from Realm it no longer run the state validations or require open realm connection.

Any ideas what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing some code, but are you sure you are accessing the object **returned** from `copyFromRealm` and you are not still accessing the original object?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what part of the code would help.. All I'm doing is querying the Realm, calling copyFromRealm to the result and storing the object. Then later on I'm calling one of the accessories on that object returned from the copyFromRealm.

Comment: The documentation is a bit vague in Realm. I'm not sure if the copy call creates a new object or unlinks the one that is in the realm. In any case I'm using the one returned by the copy call..

Comment: There we go. Totally my fault. You were actually right! Thanks for the help!